# I am trying to Download Multiple images as a zip file using laravel but i am getting error

Tags: laravel

I am trying to download multiple images as a zip file but unfortunately I am getting errors when I click to download button. Does anyone have an idea how can I resolve this issue?

I am getting an error please check it: https://flareapp.io/share/DPy2DVg7

##### `dd($files);`

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => "http://localhost/yourstitchart.com/web/public/uploads/images/phpCM0Yia.png"
  1 => "http://localhost/yourstitchart.com/web/public/uploads/images/phptLC57a.png"
]
```

##### `InboxCOntroller`

```php
public function dowloads($id)
{
    $url = config('yourstitchart.file_url');
    $inboxFiles = Inbox::where('id', $id)->first()->file;

    $files = [];
    foreach (json_decode($inboxFiles) as $i => $value) {
        $files[$i] = $url . $value;
    }
    // dd($files);

    $inbox = Inbox::find($id);
    $folderName = $inbox->id . '-' . str_replace(' ', '-', $inbox->order_name);
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $zipFile = $url . $folderName . '/' . $folderName . '.zip';

    if ($zip->open($zipFile, ZipArchive::CREATE) === true) {
        //add files into a zip
        foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
            //replace word "full" with $portfolioImage->id
            $relativeNameInZipFile = str_replace('full', $key, basename($value));
            $zip->addFile($value, $relativeNameInZipFile);
        }

        $zip->close();
    }

    return response()->download($zipFile);
}
```

Comment: Instead of doing `Inbox::where('id', $id)->first()`, you can do `Inbox::find($id)` and it is exactly the same (and you should be using `find`). Also, instead of `json_decode` for `->file`, you have to [cast](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting) `file` as an array... If you are using `json_decode` in your Laravel code for local code (not for consuming APIs) you are doing something wrong... not the Laravel way... and your code is pretty strange, you are getting an `Inbox` and then after the `foreach`, you are getting exactly the same `Inbox` again...

Answer (score 0):

You getting 404 **File not found exception**. Make sure the zip file is created before adding the images inside that zip.

```
public function dowloads()
{
    $files = [
        0 => ('assets/images/icon/01.png'),
        1 => ('assets/images/icon/02.png')
    ];

    $zip = new \ZipArchive;
    $zipFile = 'zip-file.zip';

    if ($zip->open(public_path($zipFile), ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE){
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $pathToFile = public_path($file);
            
            $name = basename($pathToFile);

            $zip->addFile($pathToFile, $name);
        }
        $zip->close();
    }
    return response()->download(public_path($zipFile));
}
```

Comment: please can explain to me a/c to my code ? thanks.

Comment: You have to use public_path or storage_path to create and fetch files.
Maybe you don't need the $url variable for fetching. So try without $url